# ElasticSearch 5.5 ParsingException[[sort] query malformed, no start_object after query name]

Tags: java, elasticsearch-5

I've a query which runs in Sense/Kibana Dev tool, doesn't run while executing using Java API-Transport Client

Query:

```
{\"sort\": [{\"_score\": {\"order\": \"desc\"}},{\"CREATED_DATE\": {\"order\": \"desc\"}}],\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"filter\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": []}},"+
"\"must\": {\"bool\": {\"should\": [{\"bool\": {\"should\": [{\"match_phrase_prefix\": {\"property\": \"value\"}}]}}]}}}},\"from\": 0,\"size\": 2000}
```

Java:

```
WrapperQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(Query);

SearchRequestBuilder req = client.prepareSearch("myIndex").setTypes("myType").setQuery(builder);

MultiSearchResponse Res = client.prepareMultiSearch().add(req).get();
```

Result:

> Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
>   ParsingException[[sort] query malformed, no start_object after query
>   name]